# deallocate objects that live in a thread that has just ended, by connecting the finished() signal to QObject::deleteLater()

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

From: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details

> From Qt 4.8 onwards, it is possible to deallocate objects that live in a thread that has just ended, by connecting the finished() signal to QObject::deleteLater().

Does this mean if I connect finished() signal to QObject::deleteLater() I won't have to worry about memory leaks in the worker thread?

What objects of worker thread class is it going to deallocate on its own?

`connect(workerThread, &WorkerThread::finished, workerThread, &QObject::deleteLater);` 
From : doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details

They have shown workerthread's object connected to deleteLater slot. Now does this mean that all objects which I allocate memory to inside the worker class will get automatically deleted?

Comment: **Not at all.** You are connecting the `workerThread`'s `finished()` signal **to its own** `deleteLater()`. This is not what is meant by the docs (as this will cause undefined behavior when your `workerThread` is not allocated dynamically). Instead, you need to connect `finished()` signal to a worker object's `deleteLater()`. The worker object should be living in the worker thread (by using `moveToThread(workerThread)`)...

Comment: @Mike Please show the example. What i have written there is written in the docs.

Comment: The quote is indeed from the docs, but it doesn't mean that you should connect the thread's `finished()` signal **to its own** `deleteLater()`. Usually, you connect the `finished()` signal **to another worker** QObject's `deleteLater()`, so that the worker object is destroyed when the thread is finished. I don't have time to provide a complete example now, but I'll try to post one later...

Comment: Does it mean that main thread's finished signal should be connected to worker's deleteLater? @Mike

Comment: Exactly. Usually, you don't need to subclass QThread. Instead, have a worker QObject that hosts the code that needs to be executed in the worker thread, then move that worker object to the thread and start it after connecting the finished signal from the thread to the worker's deleteLater...

Comment: @Mike The example is already in the docs. The one above the example OP referred to.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl, the example provided in the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details) (as mentioned by @thuga) shows how this should be done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a `QThread` ends (when it `run()` method returns) it sends the signal `QThread::finished`.
Every `QObject` whose `deleteLater` slot is connected to this signal gets deleted.

If you connect the `QThread::finished()` signal to `QObject::deleteLater()` method of the worker object as mentioned in the documentation of `QThread` (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details), then the worker is deleted after the `QThread` has finished.
All other `QObjects` which you have created within the worker will still exist.
If you want them to be deleted too you have to either connect them to the same QThread::finished() signal or you use the parent-child-mechanism by setting the worker object as parent of the other object (either by passing it as parent in the constructor (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#QObject) or by setting it explicitly with `void QObject::setParent(QObject *parent)` (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setParent).

Answer (score 1):

> What objects is it going to deallocate on its own?

The objects whose `deleteLater` slot you connected.

But you have it backwards, it seems: threading and object lifetimes are orthogonal issues. Just because stuff runs in some other thread doesn't mean that somehow it will leak - not unless you just totally gave up on object lifetime management.

Imagine that your objects live in the main thread. How will you manage their lifetime? Do the same thing in the worker. It's also not necessary to end the object lifetimes in the worker thread. You can push them back to the main thread, end the worker thread, and destroy them in the main thread. Etc. Threading doesn't introduce any new problems here: you had the problem from the beginning. Solve it, then add threading and it won't reappear :)